# probability notation

Tags: probability, notation

**Part A)**

I have the following notations :

1. $p(\mu, \sigma^2)$
2. $N(x)$
3. $p(x | \mu, \sigma^2)$

I would read them in the following manner:

1. probability function with 2 parameters, namely $\mu$
   and $\sigma^2$
2. normal distribution of variable $x$
3. distribution of variable $x$ with parameters $\mu$
   and $\sigma^2$

**Part B)**

If the above is correct, then please check my interpretation of :

1. $p(x,y)$
2. $p(x | y,a,b,c,d)$

my interpretation :

1. probabilty function of 2 independent variables
2. probability of variable $x$, given the probability for $y$ and parameters $a,b,c$ are known

**Part C)**

The follwoing notation is equal

$p(y∣x)$ is equal to  $p_{Y∣X}(y∣x)$ is equal to $P(Y=y∣X=x)$

and the above notaitons in **Part A** and **Part B** can be rewritten in similar manner.

---

I would conclude my understanding as follows:

$p(variable|parameters)$

where the $variable$ is the input to the function $p(x)$, and the $parameters$ are the parameters of $p(...)$ and as such, need to be known prior to the evaluation of $p(x)$

---

**Question 1**: is the above correct ?

**Question 2**: is there any other common interpretation, that one can be mistaken with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark. I will refer to all these functions with probability density function (=continuous setting). All the statements remain true when replacing probability density function with probability mass function. (=discrete setting)

Part A.

> 1. probability function with 2 parameters, namely $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

No, this should be a probability density function (pdf) of two random variables $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

> 2. normal distribution of variable $x$

Writing just $N(x)$ is a bit weird, I would say it is a pdf of the random variable $x$.

> 3. [...]

Right.

Part B.

> 1. probabilty function of 2 independent variables

This is a pdf again, but the 2 variables $x, y$ do not need to be independent. They were independent, if $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$.

> probability of variable $x$, given the probability for $y$ and parameters $a,b,c$ are known

Without context, it is not clear, whether $y$ is a realisation of a random variable and $a,b,c$ are not. For the definition, they do not need to be. Just say: Probability density function of $x$ given $y,a,b,c$.

Part C. This is correct, if the probability density functions are actually probability mass functions. Otherwise, it is wrong.

I think you got the concept pretty well.

Comment: A.1 may be correct depending on how and where it is used, e.g. $X \sim p(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: Yes, but then $p(\mu, \sigma^2)(\cdot)$ would be a _probability measure_, and the notation above pretty inconsistent. But that is possible. Sure.